# How to use the ratio test for series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification

I would like to know whether the following reasoning to solve certain exercises concerning series is correct: suppose we have a sequence $\{a_n \}:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $a_n=a_n(x)$ (for instance, $a_n=\frac{x^n}{n!}$). To show that the sum of the $a_n$'s is convergent, we agree to use the ratio test and we find that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} |=l=l(x)$. To find the values of $x$ for which the sum is convergent, is it right to study when $l<1$ and then treat separately the case in which $l=1$ (that is, studying the series for a given value of $x$)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you should do. Although in your example ($a_n=\frac{x^n}{n!}$) $l=0$ for any possible value of $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much!